# Visual studio cordova blank app build is failing

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, build, output

I am doing my first project in Visual Studio Apache Cordova App.

I did all the installations and recommended configurations, but still has some error.

below is the output.

```
NuGet package restore started. Restoring NuGet packages for solution
c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.sln. NuGet
Package restored finished for solution
c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.sln. Restoring
NuGet packages for project BlankCordovaAppTest1. Restoring NuGet
packages listed in file c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\packages.config.
Skipping NuGet package cordova.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 0.8.2 since
it is already installed. NuGet Package restored finished for project
BlankCordovaAppTest1. All packages are already installed and there is
nothing to restore. NuGet package restore finished. 1>------ Build
started: Project: BlankCordovaAppTest1, Configuration: Debug Android
------ 1>Build started 11/06/2015 15:53:24. 1>Building with tools version "12.0". 1>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in
file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(entry point): 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (
'$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' ==
'true' ). 1>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; (
'$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' ==
'true' ). 1>Using "Message" task from assembly
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "Message" 1    
Configuration=Debug 1>Done executing task "Message". 1>Task "Message"
1     Platform=Android 1>Done executing task "Message". 1>Task "Error"
skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and
!HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\Android\Debug\'
!= '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bin\Android\Debug\')). 1>Task "Error"
skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' !=
'' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was
evaluated as ('bld\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bld\')). 1>Task
"Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)'
!= '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was
evaluated as ('bld\Android\Debug\' != '' and
!HasTrailingSlash('bld\Android\Debug\')). 1>Done building target
"_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in project
"BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target "EntityDeploy" skipped, due to
false condition; ('@(EntityDeploy)' != '') was evaluated as ('' !=
''). 1>Target "BeforeBuild" in file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target "BeforeBuild"
in project "BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target "CoreBuild" in file
"C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target "CoreBuild" in
project "BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target
"CreateTfsBuildInfoResource" skipped, due to false condition; (
$(AddBuildInfoToAssembly)==true ) was evaluated as ( false==true ).
1>Target "AfterBuild" in file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target "AfterBuild" in
project "BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target "BuildOnlySettings" in
file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from
project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target
"BuildOnlySettings" in project "BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target
"PreComputeCompileTypeScript" in file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "CompileTypeScript" depends on it): 1>Using "VsTsc" task from
assembly "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll".
1>Task "VsTsc" 1     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\tsc.exe  --sourcemap --target ES5  --locale en-US
COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\index.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\platformOverrides.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\cordova.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\BatteryStatus.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Camera.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Contacts.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Device.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\DeviceMotion.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\DeviceOrientation.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Dialogs.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\FileSystem.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\FileTransfer.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Globalization.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\InAppBrowser.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Media.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\MediaCapture.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\NetworkInformation.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Push.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Splashscreen.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Vibration.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\WebSQL.d.ts"
1>Done executing task "VsTsc". 1>Using "AssignTargetPath" task from
assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task
"AssignTargetPath" 1>Done executing task "AssignTargetPath". 1>Done
building target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" in project
"BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target "CompileTypeScript" in file
"C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "BuildRipple" depends on it): 1>Building target
"CompileTypeScript" completely. 1>Output file "scripts\index.js" does
not exist. 1>Task "VsTsc" 1     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\tsc.exe  --sourcemap --target ES5  --locale en-US
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\index.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\platformOverrides.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\cordova.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\BatteryStatus.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Camera.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Contacts.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Device.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\DeviceMotion.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\DeviceOrientation.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Dialogs.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\FileSystem.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\FileTransfer.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Globalization.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\InAppBrowser.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Media.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\MediaCapture.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\NetworkInformation.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Push.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Splashscreen.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\Vibration.d.ts"
"c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\scripts\typings\cordova\plugins\WebSQL.d.ts"
1>Done executing task "VsTsc". 1>Done building target
"CompileTypeScript" in project "BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target
"CompileTypescript" skipped. Previously built successfully. 1>Target
"TrackJsChanges" in file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "BuildRipple" depends on it): 1>Task "Message" 1    
GeneratedJavascript=scripts\index.js;scripts\index.js.map;scripts\platformOverrides.js;scripts\platformOverrides.js.map;scripts\index.js;scripts\index.js.map;scripts\platformOverrides.js;scripts\platformOverrides.js.map
1>Done executing task "Message". 1>Using "MakeDir" task from assembly
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "MakeDir" 1     Creating
directory "bld\Ripple\Android\Debug". 1>Done executing task "MakeDir".
1>Using "MdaTrackJsChanges" task from assembly "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>Task "MdaTrackJsChanges" 1>Done executing task "MdaTrackJsChanges".
1>Task "MdaTrackJsChanges" skipped, due to false condition;
('$(DebuggerFlavor)' != '' AND $(DebuggerFlavor.Substring(0,6)) !=
'Ripple') was evaluated as ('RippleNexus' != '' AND Ripple !=
'Ripple'). 1>Done building target "TrackJsChanges" in project
"BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj". 1>Target "PrepareForRippleRequirements"
in file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "BuildRipple" depends on it): 1>Building target
"PrepareForRippleRequirements" completely. 1>Output file
"bld\Debug\platforms\android\assets\www\config.xml" does not exist.
1>Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0,
Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "CallTarget" 1>Target
"EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in file "C:\Program
Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" depends on it): 1>Task "Error"
skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true'
And $(NodeJsDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == 'true' And
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ == ''). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to
false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true' And
$(MDAVsixDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == 'true' And C:\PROGRAM
FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0IVLVFVN.URX == ''). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And
$(NodeJsDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == '' And C:\Program Files
(x86)\nodejs\ == ''). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition;
($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And $(MDAVsixDir) == '') was
evaluated as (true == '' And C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL
STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0IVLVFVN.URX == ''). 1>Task "Error"
skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(NodeJsDir)') Or
!Exists('$(NodeJsDir)\node.exe')) was evaluated as
(!Exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\') Or !Exists('C:\Program
Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe')). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false
condition; (!Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)') Or
!Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)\packages\vs-mda')) was evaluated as
(!Exists('C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0IVLVFVN.URX') Or !Exists('C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0IVLVFVN.URX\packages\vs-mda')). 1>Task "CallTarget" 1>Target "InstallMDATargets" in file "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
from project "c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj"
(target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" depends on it):
1>Using "RunMdaTargetsInstall" task from assembly "C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>Task "RunMdaTargetsInstall" 1     c:\users\thadeu\documents\visual
studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1>call
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat  1     Your environment
has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.4 (x64) and npm. 1     ------
Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package
directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0IVLVFVN.URX\packages\vs-mda 1     ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda 1     ------ Version from source
package.json: 0.1.75 1     ------ Package not currently installed
globally. 1     ------ Installing globally from source package. This
could take a few minutes... 1     npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 1     npm
ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g"
"install" "C:\\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\\COMMON7\\IDE\\EXTENSIONS\\0IVLVFVN.URX\\packages\\vs-mda" 1     npm ERR! node v0.12.4 1     npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1 1     npm ERR! code
ETIMEDOUT 1     npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT 1     npm ERR! syscall connect 1>
npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 1     npm ERR! network This is most
likely not a problem with npm itself 1     npm ERR! network and is
related to network connectivity. 1     npm ERR! network In most cases
you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. 1     npm ERR!
network  1     npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make
sure that the 1     npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. 
See: 'npm help config' 1     npm ERR! Please include the following file
with any support request: 1     npm ERR!    
c:\Users\Thadeu\Documents\Visual Studio
2013\Projects\BlankCordovaAppTest1\BlankCordovaAppTest1\npm-debug.log
1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error : fs.js:500 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
stringToFlags(flags), mode); 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :                  ^ 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error : Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
'C:\Users\Thadeu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\BuildSettings.js'
1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at Error (native) 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18) 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1099:15) 1>C:\Program
Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0ivlvfvn.urx\packages\vs-mda\install.js:62:16
1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at Array.forEach (native) 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at copyFiles (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio
12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0ivlvfvn.urx\packages\vs-mda\install.js:59:17)
1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at ChildProcess.<anonymous    (C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0ivlvfvn.urx\packages\vs-mda\install.js:98:13)
1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(207,5):
error :     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(child_process.js:1074:12) 1>Done executing task
"RunMdaTargetsInstall". 1>Task "CallTarget" skipped, due to false
condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) == '-17') was evaluated as (1 ==
'-17'). 1>Using "Error" task from assembly
"Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "Error" 1>C:\Program Files
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(219,5):
error : Error installing local npm package. 1>Done executing task
"Error" -- FAILED. 1>Done building target "InstallMDATargets" in
project "BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj" -- FAILED. 1>Done executing task
"CallTarget" -- FAILED. 1>Done building target
"EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in project
"BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj" -- FAILED. 1>Done executing task
"CallTarget" -- FAILED. 1>Done building target
"PrepareForRippleRequirements" in project
"BlankCordovaAppTest1.jsproj" -- FAILED. 1    1>Build FAILED. 1    1>Time
Elapsed 00:02:18.89
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Kindly help me on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the errors:

npm ERR! node v0.12.4 1     npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1 1     npm ERR! code
ETIMEDOUT 1     npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT 1     npm ERR! syscall connect 1>
npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 1     npm ERR! network This is most
likely not a problem with npm itself 1     npm ERR! network and is
related to network connectivity. 1     npm ERR! network In most cases
you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. 1     npm ERR!
network  1     npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make
sure that the 1     npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. 
See: 'npm help config' 1     npm ERR! Please include the following file
with any support request: 1     npm ERR!

Looks like it is a network issue.